# NSUserDefaults and persistency in a UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a quick coding question. First off, I am using XCode 8 and swift 2. Here is a quick image of my viewcontroller so you can get a better idea. [Image of my viewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f82Ws.png)

In the above image, you insert a goal (text into the text field) and press submit. The submit button ("Submit Goal") inserts the text from the text field into an array. This array is then displayed in the tableview.

My question is, how do I implement NSUserDefualts into this viewcontroller to save the array? This also needs to be able to update the array if a user deletes one of the goals from the tableview.

Here is my code for the viewcontroller at the moment:

```
//
//  VCWeeklyGoals.swift
//  FitNote
//
//  Created by ---- on 9/21/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Haiden Stiles. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class VCWeeklyGoals: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties








//DATE AND TIME
@IBOutlet weak var labelDate: UILabel!
var timer = NSTimer()

@objc func tick() {
    labelDate.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .MediumStyle)
}
//END DATE AND TIME

//BEGINNING ROUNDED BUTTONS FOR MONDAY THROUGH FRIDAY
//@IBOutlet weak var roundedButtonMonday: UIButton!


    //ROUNDED BUTTON FOR SUBMIT GOAL
@IBOutlet weak var roundedButtonSubmitGoal: UIButton!
    //END ROUNDED BUTTON FOR SUBMIT GOAL

//END ROUNDED BUTTONS FOR MONDAY THROUGH FRIDAY







//BEGINNING OF TABLE FUNCTIONS AND PROPERTIES

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var insertedGoal: UITextField!

//var tableTitles = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("tableTitles") as! [String]
var tableTitles = [String]()




@IBAction func buttonSubmitGoal(sender: UIButton) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    var error = ""

    if insertedGoal.text == "" {

        error = "Please enter a goal!"
    } else {

        tableTitles.append(insertedGoal.text!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if error != "" {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Error In Form", message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

            //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

    insertedGoal.text = ""

}



//func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//    return 1
//}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableTitles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = tableTitles[indexPath.row] 
    cell.textLabel!.text = object

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        tableTitles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}

//END OF TABLE FUNCTIONS AND PROPERTIES



//OVERRIDE FUNCTIONS

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    if let temp = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("tableTitles") as? [String] {
        tableTitles = temp
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //TABLE PROPERTIES
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.insertedGoal.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    //END TABLE PROPERTIES

    //DATE PROPERTIES
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(tick),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
    //END DATE PROPERTIES

    //ROUNDED BUTTON FOR MONDAY THROUGH FRIDAY PROPERTIES
    //MONDAY
    //roundedButtonMonday.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    //roundedButtonMonday.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    //roundedButtonMonday.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    //roundedButtonMonday.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor


        //ROUNDED BUTTON FOR SUBMIT GOAL
    roundedButtonSubmitGoal.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    roundedButtonSubmitGoal.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    roundedButtonSubmitGoal.layer.borderWidth = 1
    roundedButtonSubmitGoal.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

        //END ROUNDED BUTTON FOR SUBMIT GOAL
    //END ROUNDED BUTTON FOR MONDAY THROUGH FRIDAY PROPERTIES

    //DATE PICKER

    //END DATE PICKER
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Don't use `NSUserDefaults` to save data. That is not its purpose. Write your array to a file using the methods of `NSArray`.

Comment: I was looking at NSArray, but I felt like I wasn't making any progress with it... Would you mind steering me in the right direction to implementing NSArray?

Answer (score 0):

I had been working on your question, and this is my solution

First of all I create a model for goal, is a simple one, this only have the text of the goal, and also two static methods, one for save and the other for load

```
class Goal: NSObject {

var text : String = ""

init(text: String) {
    super.init()
    self.text = text
}

static func loadFromFile(fileName:String) ->[Goal]?
{
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true);
    let docsDirectory = paths[0];
    let path = docsDirectory + "/" + fileName;
    let data = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path);

    if(data != nil)
    {
        var returnArray : [Goal] = []
        for object in data! {
            returnArray.append(Goal(text: object as! String))
        }
        return returnArray
    }

    return nil
}

static func saveToPlist(filename:String,goals:[Goal]) -> Bool {

    let toSaveArray = NSMutableArray();
    for goal in goals {
        toSaveArray.add(goal.text)
    }

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true);
    let docsDirectory = paths[0];
    let path = docsDirectory + "/" + filename;
    return toSaveArray.write(toFile: path, atomically: true);
}

}
```

and here is my implementation on my `ViewController`, and the `GoalTableViewCell` is a simple cell with only one `UILabel`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tfGoalTextAdd: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btnAdd: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var goals : [Goal] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
    self.loadGoals()
    self.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addGoalWithTextFieldText), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func loadGoals()
{
    if let arrayGoals = Goal.loadFromFile(fileName: "goals")
    {
        self.goals = arrayGoals
    }
}

public func addGoalWithTextFieldText()
{
    if(self.tfGoalTextAdd.text != nil && self.tfGoalTextAdd.text != "")
    {
        self.addGoal(text: self.tfGoalTextAdd.text!)
        self.tfGoalTextAdd.text = ""
    }
}

public func addGoal(text: String)
{
    self.goals.append(Goal(text: text))
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    if(Goal.saveToPlist(filename: "goals", goals: goals))
    {
        debugPrint("Successful saved")
    }
}

public func removeGoal(goal:Goal)
{
    goals.remove(at:goals.index(of: goal)!)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    if(Goal.saveToPlist(filename: "goals", goals: goals))
    {
        debugPrint("Successful saved")
    }
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.goals.count
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalCell") as! GoalTableViewCell
    cell.setupWithGoal(goal: self.goals[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .delete
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        //tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.removeGoal(goal: self.goals[indexPath.row])

        //tableView.endUpdates()

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}


}
```

I hope this helps you